# Should I be using else-if statements for these?

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm very new to coding, and have been trying to create a very simple calculator using HTML and JavaScript where the user inputs two values, selects an operator from a selection of buttons, and then gets a result.

I'd appreciate some guidance from people who know what they're doing!!

I've tried implementing else-ifs, but it doesn't appear to be solving the issue. Only the last line of the function is executing. Python wasn't this hard?!

```
<button id="a" value="+">+</button>
<button id="b" value="-">-</button>
<button id="c" value="/">/</button>
<button id="d" value="X">X</button>

<input type="text" id="n1"/>
<input type="text" id="n2"/>
```

```
<script>
    function calc()
    {
        var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('n1').value);
        var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('n2').value);

        var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
        var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
        var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
        var d = document.getElementById("d").value;

        if(a === '+')
        {
            document.getElementById('result').value = n1+n2;
        }
        if(b === '-')
        {
            document.getElementById('result').value = n1-n2;
        }
        if(c === '/')
        {
            document.getElementById('result').value = n1/n2;
        }
        if(d === 'X')
        {
            document.getElementById('result').value = n1*n2;
        }
    }

</script>
```

I'm expecting each line to be executed to produce the correct operand, but at present the only last line (n1*n2) is giving me anything.

Comment: Your `if` conditions are all true. They don't have anything to do with what button the user clicked.

Comment: The button's value doesn't change depending on whether the user clicked on it.

Comment: There's no jQuery code here, just plain JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, an obvious error on my part!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your conditions are true, since the value of a button doesn't change depending on whether the user clicked on it.

You should change `calc()` so it takes the button as a parameter, then checks the value of the parameter's value. A `switch` statement is an easy way to write this type of check.

```js
function calc(button) {
  var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('n1').value);
  var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('n2').value);
  let result;
  switch (button.value) {
    case '+':
      result = n1 + n2;
      break;
    case '-':
      result = n1 - n2;
      break;
    case '/':
      result = n1 / n2;
      break;
    case 'X':
      result = n1 * n2;
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById('result').value = result;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="n1" />
<input type="text" id="n2" /><br>
<button id="a" value="+" onclick="calc(this)">+</button>
<button id="b" value="-" onclick="calc(this)">-</button>
<button id="c" value="/" onclick="calc(this)">/</button>
<button id="d" value="X" onclick="calc(this)">X</button>
<br>
<input type="text" id="result" readonly />
```